# Why does calling a Rust library from C result in memory leakage?

Tags: c, memory, rust, memory-leaks, ffi

I'm trying to prove that C can call a Rust library. It works, but when I monitor the memory usage of my program, it keeps on getting bigger and bigger.

Cargo.toml:

```
[lib]
name="test_ccallr"
crate-type=["cdylib"]
path = "src/lib.rs"

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2"
```

C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Payload_t{
    char* data;
    int len;
};

int show_str(char* raw, struct Payload_t *data);

int main()
{
    while(1){
        char * p_raw = "hlease print it !ello this is string from c, please print it !";
        char * p_raw_ = "hhello this is another  ";

        char * pp = (char* )malloc(strlen(p_raw));
        memcpy(pp, p_raw, strlen(p_raw));

        struct Payload_t *tmp = (struct Payload_t*)malloc(sizeof (struct Payload_t));
        struct Payload_t *_tmp = tmp;
        tmp->data = (char*)malloc(strlen(p_raw_));
        memcpy(tmp->data, p_raw_, strlen(p_raw_));
        tmp->len = strlen(p_raw_);
        printf("\n%d   %d   %d", pp, tmp, tmp->data);
        show_str(pp, tmp);
        printf("\n%d   %d   %d", pp, tmp, tmp->data);
        free(pp);
        free(tmp->data);
        //free(_tmp);
        usleep(5);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I build my C code with the following command:

```
gcc main.c -L ./ -Bstatic -l:libtest_ccallr.so -o test[lib]
```

Rust code:

```rust
//use std::os::raw::{c_char, c_int};
extern crate libc;
use libc::{c_char, c_int};
use std::error::Error;
use std::ffi::CStr;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct Payload_t {
    data: *const u8,
    len: c_int,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn show_str(raw: *const c_char, data: *const Payload_t) -> i32 {
    let c_str: &CStr = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(raw) };
    if let Err(err) = c_str.to_str() {
        eprintln!("{}", err.description());
        return 0;
    }
    let str_from_ptr = c_str.to_str().unwrap();

    let payload_ptr: Payload_t = unsafe { *Box::from_raw(data as *mut Payload_t) };

    let payload = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(payload_ptr.data, payload_ptr.len as usize) };

    println!("the raw string is {}", str_from_ptr);
    println!(
        "the length string is {}",
        std::str::from_utf8(payload).unwrap()
    );

    return 0;
}
```

If I uncomment `//free(_tmp);`, the program will crash. If I keep this line commented, and run the program, it can run, but it leaks memory.

Is there anything that is not proper?

Comment: Why do you have both `tmp` and `_tmp` which appear to be exactly the same thing?

Comment: Your habit of having two almost but not quite the same variable names differentiated by an underscore is something you need to deal with. Seeing `p_raw` and `p_raw_` together, as different things, is what you'd expect to see in deliberately obfuscated code, it's not a good plan.

Comment: `tmp->data = (char*)malloc(strlen(p_raw_));
        memcpy(tmp->data, p_raw_, strlen(p_raw_));` <<-- One too short; the *string* wont be NUL-terminated.

Comment: Tip: `strdup()` instead of `malloc()` + `memcpy()`.

Comment: finally ! I find the problem ... after  ```show_str(pp, tmp);``` is called, the variable ```tmp``` is taken over by rust, and  the value of  ```tmp->data```  is NULL(```tmp ``` is not null , interesting...). So ```free(tmp->data);``` failed to free memory . This is the problem !!!

Answer (score 5):

This is an **inappropriate usage** of `Box::from_raw`:

```rust
let payload_ptr: Payload_t = unsafe { *Box::from_raw(data as *mut Payload_t) };
```

From the documentation, emphasis mine (**please** read the documentation for unsafe functions):

> After calling this function, the raw pointer is owned by the resulting `Box`. Specifically, **the `Box` destructor will call the destructor of `T` and free the allocated memory**. For this to be safe, the memory must have been allocated in accordance with the memory layout used by `Box`.

You should only use this function for data that was allocated by `Box::new` that you are retaking ownership of. Your case is neither. `Box` is deallocating the memory allocated by C. That's most likely what is causing your call to `free` to crash, as Rust has scribbled over the memory with it's own destructor.

A better way of writing your Rust function does not attempt to take ownership of `data`:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn show_str(raw: *const c_char, data: *const Payload_t) -> i32 {
    let c_str = CStr::from_ptr(raw);
    let str_from_ptr = match c_str.to_str() {
        Ok(s) => s,
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("{}", err);
            return 0;
        }
    };

    let payload_ptr = &*data;
    let payload = std::slice::from_raw_parts(payload_ptr.data, payload_ptr.len as usize);
    let s = match std::str::from_utf8(payload) {
        Ok(s) => s,
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("{}", err);
            return 0;
        }
    };

    println!("the raw string is {}", str_from_ptr);
    println!("the length string is {}", s);

    0
}
```